# What’s the difference between “disordered” and “disorderly”?

Tags: single-word-requests

I looked up the dictionary, and I found that they have pretty much the same meaning. Under what circumstances are these two words used and how the usage is different?

For instance, in the sentence, "A disorderly evacuation ensued.", can I say "A disordered evacuation ensued."?

Comment: A little more dictionary work would reveal differences between these two words. The description "pretty much the same" is too vague to allow us to help resolve your difficulty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Disordered* usually refers to inanimate objects, and *disorderly* usually refers to some type of action or behavior.  For *disordered,* think about how molecules arrange themselves at a certain temperature -- do they form a lattice, for example?  That would be a very ordered arrangement.

For *disorderly*, think of the misdemeanor "disorderly conduct."

No, "A disordered evacuation ensued" isn't idiomatic.  You'd want to say "A disorderly evacuation ensued."  "Disordered" is more static -- it's more about the end result than the process.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the points in the answer from @Ricky, I would mention one specific usage of ‘disorderly’ that does not relate to ‘order’ (except, perhaps, in a moral sense):

> A **house** might be left in a state of **disorder** after a burglary,

but…

> A [**disorderly house**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disorderly%20house?utm_campaign=sd&utm_medium=serp&utm_source=jsonld) is another term for a **brothel**.

*And in answer to the specific example question…*

**No.** A “disordered evacuation ensued”, though comprehensible, would sound strange (as explained in the other answer). In fact, if you run a [Google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=disordered+evacuation%2C+disorderly+evacuation&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdisordered%20evacuation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdisorderly%20evacuation%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cdisordered%20evacuation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdisorderly%20evacuation%3B%2Cc0) on “disordered evacuation” and “disorderly evacuation” you do find the former has recently risen in frequency. However if you look at the actual books involved, the examples of “disordered evacuation” relate to surgical procedures, whereas those of “disorderly evacuation” relate to military manoeuvres.

Answer (score 1):

*Disordered* applies more often, but not always, to matters for which order is a natural state. Such as body organs or army formation.

*Disorderly* is more often used with matters that are not naturally characterized by strict order - such as crowd behavior or the position of various objects on one's desk.